# Using Simple Voice Commands in Unity3D (with IBM Watson SDK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, cross-platform, ibm-watson, voice-recognition

## The problem

I'm currently using **Speech-To-Text from the [IBM Watson SDK for Unity](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk)** to recognize **voice commands** like **start** or **quit** by just **checking if the recognized text contains one** of them.

Problem is that it **doesn't work very reliable** (output is often *spot* or *hit*) and I really just need those simple commands.

## What I tried

Alternatively I already tried `using UnityEngine.Windows.Speed;` but I **need it to work on both Windows and Mac**. I couldn't find a good and working Mac solution and I tried writing my own Unity plugin with Xcode and *NSSpeechRecognizer* similar to this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@SoCohesive/unity-how-to-build-a-bridge-ios-to-unity-with-swift-f23653f6261) but that didn't work for me.

I also saw [Snowboy](https://snowboy.kitt.ai) for hotword detection. But it requires a lot of setup and I would really wish for an easy and reliable solution.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use both Watson Speech to Text and Assistant services for this use case. You can 
train an instance of Assistant to understand phrases like "start", "go", "initialize", etc to return an intent of `START` and phrases like "stop", "quit", "halt", etc to return an intent of `QUIT`. You can then send transcription of Speech to Text to the Assistant service which will return an intent of `START` or `QUIT` and execute game logic based on the returned intent.